# Constructed string for style value not working

Tags: javascript, string, dom, css-transforms

```
function tickleTux() {

var tuxImg = document.getElementById('tux');

tuxImg.style.transition = "transform .5s";

tuxImg.addEventListener('click', itTickles, false);

function itTickles() {

    var addRotation = 10;

    var rotationValue = '"' + 'rotate' + '(' + addRotation + 'deg' + ')' + '"' 

    tuxImg.style.transform = rotationValue;

     console.log(rotationValue);  
}
```

Basically, this adds a rotation style to an img and makes it rotate.

I **just want to know why** adding the value to the transform property *in this way* doesn't work. Why?

The console.log command prints out: "rotate(10deg)"

So what's stopping it from functioning? Some kind of rule?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value shouldn't contain `"` around it.

```
var rotationValue = 'rotate(' + addRotation + 'deg)';
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. 

I thought it needed them since it needs them when simply using the
default: element.style.transform = "rotate(10deg)";   syntax.